# INSERT not working with PDO prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am upgrading my site to use PDO. Most of the code has worked fine but I have one INSERT statement which I cannot get to work. It works on my local server but not on the live site. I have checked table structures and they are identical.

This is my code

```
try {

    foreach ($unique_product_line_ids AS $key => $value) {

        $query_insertSQL = "
            INSERT INTO tblCarts (
            date_created
            , session_id
            , product_line_id
            , posted_by_id
            , quantity
            ) VALUES (
              :date_created
            , :session_id
            , :product_line_id
            , :posted_by_id
            , :quantity1
            )
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = :quantity2
                    ";
        $insertSQL = $conn->prepare($query_insertSQL);

        $insertSQL->execute(array(
            ':date_created'=>$date_created
            , ':session_id'=>$session_id
            , ':product_line_id'=>$key
            , ':posted_by_id'=>$_SESSION['member']['individual_id']
            , ':quantity1'=>$value
            , ':quantity2'=>$value
        ));

        $rc_insertSQL = $insertSQL->rowCount();

        // close connection
        $insertSQL->closeCursor();

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I have checked the values in my unique_product_line_ids array and they exists OK. I have also tried removing the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE line (with its corresponding parameter) but that has made no difference.

Comment: Any error? Is PDO installed on live site?

Comment: Just `echo $insertSQL->errorInfo()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of pros of prepared statements is that you prepare once and execute multiple times, so
I would remake your code like this:

```
try {

    $totalInserts = 0;
    
    $query_insertSQL = 
    "
        INSERT INTO tblCarts (
              date_created
            , session_id
            , product_line_id
            , posted_by_id
            , quantity
        ) 
        VALUES (
              :date_created
            , :session_id
            , :product_line_id
            , :posted_by_id
            , :quantity
        )
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            quantity = :quantity
    ";
    
    $insertSQL = $conn->prepare($query_insertSQL);
    
    
    foreach ($unique_product_line_ids AS $key => $value) 
    {
        $insertSQL->execute(array(
              ':date_created'   => $date_created
            , ':session_id'     => $session_id
            , ':product_line_id'=> $key
            , ':posted_by_id'   => $_SESSION['member']['individual_id']
            , ':quantity'       => $value
        ));

        $totalInserts += $insertSQL->rowCount();

        /**
         * to debug if any error
         */
        var_export($conn->errorInfo());
        
        // close connection - does not need anymore while you don't 
        // prepare it multiple times
        //$insertSQL->closeCursor();
        
    }

} 
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Notes:**

You can use one variable as many times as you wish,
so no need to use `:quantity1` and `:quantity2` until they are different. `:quantity` is enough.

To debug if there is an error you can use `$conn->errorInfo();` (connection level) or `$insertSQL->errorInfo();` (query level)